# How do I handle a multi-type tree system in Java?

Tags: java, tree

The RELOAD system (http://rpg.hamsterrepublic.com/ohrrpgce/RELOAD) is used in the OHRRPGCE GCS as a tree-based data containment system. A node in this system can have one of seven types and any number of children.

Currently, I am writing a library of sorts for Java to handle RELOAD via generics, but it feels like a kludge to me. Am I doing it right or is there a more efficient way?

Here is the code for an abstract RELOAD node:

```
 /**
 * 
 */
package hamsterwrench.data.reload;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Matt
 *
 */
public abstract class ReloadNode<T>{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private ArrayList<ReloadNode> children = new ArrayList<ReloadNode>();
    private T data;
    private long nodeID;
    private String name;
    protected ReloadNodeType type;

    public ReloadNode(long id, String newName){
        name = newName;
        nodeID = id;
    }

    public T readData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void writeData(T input){
        data = input;
    }

    public String name(){
        return name;
    }

    public ReloadNodeType type(){
        return type;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void addChild(ReloadNode r){
        children.add(r);
    }

    public int numberOfChildren(){
        return children.size();
    }

    public boolean removeChild(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ReloadNode r){
        return children.remove(r);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public ReloadNode getChild(int i){
        return children.get(i);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getChildrenNames(){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
            result.add(children.get(i).name());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public long ID(){
        return nodeID;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the parent's type doesn't restrict the child elements' type I don't see what you could gain from generics. We would have to see how your API would be used to better judge it, though.

Comment: Any chance you have a reference to an existing implementation(non-java probably based on the spec)?  Also, as far as Java variables go, the 8 types listed are actually 3: double, int, String.  You may want to look into a hashmap of sorts, since the data is in "String tag"-"data" format.  It's very similar to json but more compact and complicated to parse out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

However, it looks like you are re-implementing a basic tree structure. Implementing, structure efficiently is a hard and you will probably miss some subtilities.

While it is a good accademical exercice, I woudn't advice you to write your own structures for production code.

What you are probably looking is for is a Red Black Tree. Which is avaible in the package

java.util.TreeMap

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

if you need more complex tree structures. Google has created a package of highly efficent structure called Guava (free to download and use).

Here you might want to look at

com.google.common.collect.TreeBasedTable

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html

All of thoses structures are already generic.